# How to get updated list from list comprehension after remove() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

I want to get list after the if else section of the loop, but how do I get the list after operation as been done to it. Since after removing 1.00 from the list doesn't return updated list how do I set it to a variable and get that?

Note: each item in 'nls' is a list of floats, works without remove function but I need it removed if certain value exists

```
[round((sum(list(i).remove(1.00)) / len(list(i).remove(1.00))), 2)
      if 1.0 in i else sum(i) / len(i)
     for i in zip(nls[0], nls[1], nls[2])]
```

for values of i: (1.0, 214.97, 214.97), (2.0, 179.99, 179.99), (1.0, 169.99, 169.99)

I'd like to get
[214.97, 120.66, 169.99]

Comment: you need to also share with us the sample input values and desired output values so that we can better understand what you are looking for

Comment: I thought it was obvious, but added input and output

Comment: Why not just remove all `1.00`s before doing all this.

Comment: I can't before zip() the lists as the index and values not going to match, I need to remove them after zip() from the truple

Comment: Do you insist on a comprehension? There's a lot happening here. The code should be much clearer if you put this in a regular loop or move parts into predicate/processing functions (like in Paul's answer below).

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, something like this maybe?

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from statistics import mean

nls = [
    (1.0, 2.0, 1.0),
    (214.97, 179.99, 169.99),
    (214.97, 179.99, 169.99)
]

def filter_column(column):

    def predicate(value):
        from math import isclose
        return value is not None and not isclose(value, 1.0)

    return tuple(filter(predicate, column))

print(list(map(mean, map(filter_column, zip_longest(*nls, fillvalue=None)))))
```

Output:

```
[214.97, 120.66000000000001, 169.99]
>>>
```

EDIT - `itertools.zip_longest` is not required if all columns are guaranteed to have the same length (before filtering), in which case the predicate can also be changed.

Comment: Yes, that works but I was hoping something similar to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are useful to a certain extent but can't do everything.  At a certain point, they can unnecessarily make the code unreadable.  I would just stick with a good old-fashioned for-loop for this task:

```
nls = [(1.0, 214.97, 214.97), (2.0, 179.99, 179.99), (1.0, 169.99, 169.99)]
result = []
for tup in nls:
    lst = list(tup)
    if 1.0 in lst:
        lst.remove(1.0)
    ave = round(sum(lst)/len(lst),2)
    result.append(ave)
print(result)

#prints: [214.97, 120.66, 169.99]
```

Answer (score -1):

Error in the code, not removing any specific value but value of zero, so just divide by len()-1 gets the desired result